# Not able to do powerup of score - snake and ladder game | python |

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write code for snake and ladder , but seems got stuck not getting appropriate result

**My code :**

```
# Importing random module 
import random

# Snake and Ladder final destinaton  
maxCnt = 100

# Two player playing the Snake and Ladder game 
players = ['Alice','Bob']

# Snake as an Obstacle not to allow player to reach their final destination
snakes   = { 12:2 , 33:4 , 38:5 , 54:3 }

# Powerup - bonus ladder for player to reach final destination Quick  
powerupladder = { 3:16 , 18:25 , 26:10 , 28:2 , 34:2, 43:12, 54:2 , 98:1 }

# Counter - initially set to 0
counter = 0

# Initially set flag and player score to Zero 
flag = 0
player1 = 0
p1ayer2 = 0

# Logic - infinite loop to get user a chance to play everytime 
while True:

  if flag == 0:
    
    if player1 in powerupladder:
        
        player1_score = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 3 -> 0 + 16  : 16
        player1 = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 16

    else: 

      # Player throwing dice 
      p1ayer1_dice = random.randint(1, 6)
      
      if p1ayer1_dice in powerupladder:
        player1_score = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 3 -> 0 + 16  : 16
        player1 = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 16 
      else:
        player1_score = player1 + p1ayer1_dice   
        if player1_score in powerupladder:
          player1 = player1 + powerupladder[player1_score]
        else:
          player1 = player1 + p1ayer1_dice
    
    # Score 
    print('The player 1 rolling dice : ',p1ayer1_dice)

    # Score 
    print('The player 1 score : ',player1_score) 

    # Exiting with status as success if player reaches the final destination  
    if player1_score >= maxCnt:
      print(f'Congratulations {players[0]} you won the snake and ladder... you have finally reached destination')
      player1_score=0
      break
```

**Output of above code:**

```
The player 1 rolling dice :  1
The player 1 score :  1
The player 1 rolling dice :  1
The player 1 score :  2
The player 1 rolling dice :  3
The player 1 score :  18
The player 1 rolling dice :  3
The player 1 score :  34
The player 1 rolling dice :  3
The player 1 score :  50
The player 1 rolling dice :  1
The player 1 score :  51
The player 1 rolling dice :  2
The player 1 score :  53
The player 1 rolling dice :  3
The player 1 score :  69
The player 1 rolling dice :  5
The player 1 score :  74
The player 1 rolling dice :  4
The player 1 score :  78
The player 1 rolling dice :  3
The player 1 score :  94
The player 1 rolling dice :  2
The player 1 score :  96
The player 1 rolling dice :  4
The player 1 score :  100
Congratulations vikas you won the snake and ladder... you have finally reached destination
```

**Issue :**
I have `powerupladder` which double the score like

If my dice throw : `3`  then  corresponding to key: `3` the value is `16`

So my score is `16`  and next time dice is thrown it gives me `2`

So my score will be 18 -> correspond to `18` value is `25`  -> final score should be `18 + 25 : 43`

But my issue is when sum available in `pwoerupladder` it does not perform again powerup simply goes to run again dice

Please see the output shared where when score becomes `18` it runs again dice instead of `powerupladder`

Comment: You are looking up `player1_dice` in your ladder dict, when you should be looking up `player1_score`.  And wouldn't "position" be a better term than "score"?

Comment: @TimRoberts  : Yes Thanks , I have added this one `    if player1 in powerupladder:
      player1_score = player1 + powerupladder[player1]
      player1 = player1 + powerupladder[player1] `   if required any improvements please suggest so that all my scenario should be covered

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tim Roberts

I was able to get desired output

**Code :**

```
# Importing random module 
import random

# Snake and Ladder final destinaton  
maxCnt = 100

# Two player playing the Snake and Ladder game 
players = ['vikas','vamshi']

# Snake as an Obstacle not to allow player to reach their final destination
snakes   = { 12:2 , 33:4 , 38:5 , 54:3 }

# Powerup - bonus ladder for player to reach final destination Quick  
powerupladder = { 3:16 , 18:25 , 26:10 , 28:2 , 34:2, 43:12,  53:1,  54:2 , 98:1 }

# Counter - initially set to 0
counter = 0

# Initially set flag and player score to Zero 
flag = 0
player1 = 0
p1ayer2 = 0

# Logic - infinite loop to get user a chance to play everytime 
while True:

  if flag == 0:
    
    # Player throwing dice 
    p1ayer1_dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    
    if p1ayer1_dice in powerupladder:
      player1_score = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 3 -> 0 + 16  : 16
      player1 = player1 + powerupladder[p1ayer1_dice]  # 16 
    else:
      player1_score = player1 + p1ayer1_dice   
      if player1_score in powerupladder:
        player1 = player1 + powerupladder[player1_score]
      else:
        player1 = player1 + p1ayer1_dice
    
    if player1 in powerupladder:
      player1_score = player1 + powerupladder[player1]
      player1 = player1 + powerupladder[player1] 

    # Score 
    print('The player 1 Rollout dice : ',p1ayer1_dice,'Score : ',player1_score)


    # Exiting with status as success if player reaches the final destination  
    if player1_score >= maxCnt:
      print(f'Congratulations {players[0]} you won the snake and ladder... you have finally reached destination')
      player1_score=0
      break
```

**Output :**

```
The player 1 Rollout dice :  2 Score :  2
The player 1 Rollout dice :  1 Score :  43
The player 1 Rollout dice :  6 Score :  49
The player 1 Rollout dice :  6 Score :  55
The player 1 Rollout dice :  5 Score :  60
The player 1 Rollout dice :  4 Score :  64
The player 1 Rollout dice :  5 Score :  69
The player 1 Rollout dice :  3 Score :  85
The player 1 Rollout dice :  2 Score :  87
The player 1 Rollout dice :  3 Score :  103
Congratulations Alice you won the snake and ladder... you have finally reached destination
```

If more gaps are their will be filling it up.