# What's wrong with my code? And how can I fix it?

Tags: python

I have tried the following code to update the number of available cars based on the previous operations. So, for instance, if I have 3 available cars and the user rented one already, then the code should be updated to display 2 cars to the user. But whenever I ran my code, the number of available cars is always the same.

Here is my code:

```
if option_no==1:
    print("Select one of the available cars: ")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Model \t\tAvailable \tPrice/day \tLiability insurance/day \tComprehensive insurance/day")
    print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        
    camery_price = 90
    camery_availability = 3
    camery_liability_insurance = 20
    camery_comprhensive_insurance = 50
    print("1. Camery  \t\t\b\b\b\b",camery_availability, "\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR90 \t\tQR20 \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR50")

    pajero_price = 150
    pajero_liability_insurance = 30
    pajero_comprhensive_insurance = 70
    print("2. Pajero \t\t\b\b\b\b2 \t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR150 \t\tQR30  \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR70")

    altima = 70
    altima_liability_insurance = 20
    altima_comprhensive_insurance = 50
    print("3. Altima \t\t\b\b\b\b2 \t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR70 \t\tQR20  \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR50")

    car_type = int(input("Enter car type: "))
    No_of_days = int(input("Enter how many days: "))
    insurance_type = input("Enter 'L' for Liability insurance and 'F' for full insurance: ")
    if car_type==1:
        if insurance_type=='L' or insurance_type=='l':
            cost = No_of_days*camery_price
            insurance_cost = No_of_days*camery_liability_insurance
            tax = cost*0.05
            total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
            print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
            print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
            print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
            print("--------------------------------")
            print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
        elif insurance_type=='F' or insurance_type=='f':
            cost = No_of_days*camery_price
            insurance_cost = No_of_days*camery_comprhensive_insurance
            tax = cost*0.05
            total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
            print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
            print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
            print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
            print("--------------------------------")
            print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
        else:
            print("Error. Please enter the correct character")
        operation = input("More operation? [Y/N] ")
        if operation=='N' or operation=='n':
            break
    camery_availability = camery_availability - 1
```

Comment: You can greatly simplify this by putting all your constant data into a dictionary - it will effectively act as a database. Then your code is all about processing the dictionary. This also makes your code more extensible as you would only need to modify the dictionary rather than core code

Comment: Your code only runs once and therefore the output stays mostly the same. You need to create a loop.

Comment: @Mathayal : Use `while true` concept to update the flag every time @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71963396/not-able-to-do-powerup-of-score-snake-and-ladder-game-python    may be this could help you to get some idea

Comment: Instead of printing lots of tabs and backspaces (why?), use f-strings with field width specifications. For example: `f'Text {var1:10}{var2:12}'`

Comment: Move repeated code into functions. If you're testing the same variable for one of multiple possible values you can avoid repetition by doing `if insurance_type in ('L', 'l')` or if it's simply a matter of case: `if insurance_type.upper() == 'L'` (or you can use `lower()` similarly).

Comment: @codeholic24 where can I put the while loop?

Comment: @white This code is actually inside a while loop, but I just don't know how to update the camery_availability variable after each operation